# Rails - Namespaced routes in conjunction with a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, namespaces

I am trying to build some admin forms for a CMS I've created. I have recently moved the 'core' CMS models into their own modules. I am running into problems with my named routes.

I will use the Page model as an example. 
Page.rb lives in /app/models/cms/ :

```
module Cms
  Class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...page model code
  end
end
```

In config/routes.rb I have

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :things
  resources :otherthings
  scope :cms do
    resources :pages
  end
  ...more routes
end
```

In my admin views, I am using simple form. When I try to use named routes, I start running into problems:

```
=simple_form_for [:admin, @page] do |f|
```

nets me: undefined method `admin_cms_page_path'

I am unsure of how to route pages in the admin namespace such that I will get usable named routes. Should it be in a scope? This seems logical to me, but rails seems to be choking on it.

Rails: 4.2.0
Ruby 2.2.0

Comment: forgot to include the code from new pages_controller.rb in admin:  @page = Cms::Page.new

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was looking for as:

```
namespace :admin do
   scope :cms do
     resources: pages, as: "cms_pages"
```

However, if anyone has a better suggestion, they are welcome...